# A conjecture about special linear group and Fibonacci number

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, linear-groups

**Definition:**
$T_m=\{A\in M_{m\times \infty}(\Bbb{Z})\mid a_{ij}\cdot a_{i(j+1)}-a_{(i-1)(j+1)}\cdot a_{(i+1)j}=1,
\forall i\geq 2, j\geq 1,
a_{1j}=1=a_{mj}, \forall j=1,2,...\}$.

**Claim:**
$\forall m\in \Bbb{Z}^+$, $T_m\neq \emptyset$.

**Claim:**
$\forall m\in \Bbb{Z}^+$, $\#T_m<\infty$.

**Claim:**
$\forall m\in \Bbb{Z}^+$, $\forall A\in T_m$, column of $A$ has period $p(A)$.

**Conjecture:**
$$g(m)=\max_{k=1}^{\# T_m}\min\{\max A_k c_1, \max A_k c_2, \max A_k c_3,..., \max A_k c_{p(A_k)}\}$$
is $1,1,2,2,3,3,5,5,8,8,13,13,...$,
where
$c_j$ is the column vector which has $1$ at the $j$th position and $0$ elsewhere.

---

This conjecture comes from the following filling problem.
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & \cdots\\
  & a & & b && c&& d & \cdots\\
  &   & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & \cdots\\
\end{pmatrix}$,
$a, b, c, d, ...$ should satisfy
$ab-1\cdot 1=1$, 
$bc-1\cdot 1=1$, 
$cd-1\cdot 1=1$, ...

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & \cdots\\
  & a & & b && c&& d & \cdots\\
  & & \alpha & & \beta && \gamma && \delta & \cdots\\
  & &   & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & \cdots\\
\end{pmatrix}$,
$a, b, c, d, ...$, $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, ...$ should satisfy
$ab-1\cdot \alpha=1$, $bc-1\cdot \beta=1$, $cd-1\cdot \gamma=1$, ...
$\alpha \beta-b=1$, $\beta\gamma-c=1$, $\gamma\delta-d=1$, ...

[image]

For example, 
$A_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & \cdots\\
  & 1 & & 2 && 1&& 2 & \cdots\\
  &   & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & \cdots\\
\end{pmatrix}\in T_3$, $P(A_1)=2$.

Or

$A_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 && 1 & & 1 & & 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 &\cdots\\
  & 1 && 2 && 2 && 1 && 3 && 1 && 2 & \cdots\\
  && 1 && 3 && 1 && 2 && 2 && 1 && 3 & \cdots\\
  &&& 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 & \cdots\\
\end{pmatrix}\in T_4$, $P(A_1)=5$.

Write it by matrix language.
[image]

It is easy to show that 
$T_3=\left\{A_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & \cdots\\
  & 1 & & 2 && 1&& 2 & \cdots\\
  &   & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & \cdots\\
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$

and

$T_4=\left\{A_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 && 1 & & 1 & & 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 &\cdots\\
  & 1 && 2 && 2 && 1 && 3 && 1 && 2 & \cdots\\
  && 1 && 3 && 1 && 2 && 2 && 1 && 3 & \cdots\\
  &&& 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 & \cdots\\
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$.

[image]

This conjecture was given by my professor. 
He had checked it by computer with $m\leq 10$.

Comment: Hard to see what $T_m$ is... could you include the first few in the question?

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what g(m) is actually keeping track of? The max-min-max definition is difficult to parse.

Comment: One not about your numbers ($1,1,2,2,3,3,...$) is that these numbers can be generated by the sequence $a_n=a_{n-2}+a_{n-4}$ with initial values $a_0=0,a_1=a_2=a_3=1$. Maybe helpful.